# How can I set the .htaccess mod_rewrite not on localhost?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a domain and a webpage. I have been trying to create a dynamic website. It's done, but I can't configure my SEO-friendly solutions on my server, just on my local server. This is my PHP code:

```
$host = '';
$base = '/something/';
$baselength = strlen($base);
$url = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$baselength);

$url = array_merge(array('path'=>''),parse_url($url));

$get = explode('/',$url['path']);
$_GET['oldalak'] = ($get) ? array_shift($get) : '';
$_GET['aloldal'] = ($get) ? array_shift($get) : '';

$oldal = isset($_GET['pages']) ? $_GET['pages'] : '';
$oldal = 'pages/'.basename($oldal).'.php';
$oldal = (file_exists($oldal)) ? $oldal : 'pages/kezdolap.php';

$aloldal = isset($_GET['services']) ? $_GET['services'] : '';
$aloldal = 'pages/services/'.basename($aloldal).'.php';
```

This is my .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /something

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/([^/]+))? index.php?pages=$1&services=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}
</IfModule>
```

It works! But, I really do not know, what can I do, that this code work on my server.

I tried to everything. I modified to my code. This is my new code.

```
$host = 'http://something.hu';
$base = '';

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/([^/]+))? index.php?pages=$1&services=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}
</IfModule>
```

My webpage is not in a sub-directory, therefore rewrite base conditions are okay. Same as with the `$base variable`. Or not? 
I tried to modify to this:

```
$host = 'http://something.hu';
$base = 'http://something.hu';
```

I tried to modify to something else, it hasn't been working on my service provider. Why is this the case? 
Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I find the solution. 
$host = "http://something.hu";
$base = "/";

only / !!!!
Use this code, it will works!

But this wrong!!!!

$_GET['aloldal'] = ($get) ? array_shift($get) : ''; no!!!

this is the correct:  $_GET['**services**'] = ($get) ? array_shift($get) : '';

in this case...

Answer (score 0):

Your `RewriteBase` should end in a slash and be identical to your `$base` variable. For no subdirectory, they should both be just `/`